# C++ Switch Statement with While Loop

Tags: c++, while-loop, switch-statement

I have a system where user can enter as many inputs as s/he wants and make some calculations.

Here is the main loop for achieving this task:

```
int main() {
    char op;

    while(op != 'x'){
        cout << "Please select: " << endl;
        cout << "1 ---> A" << endl;
        cout << "2 ---> B" << endl;
        cout << "3 ---> C " << endl;
        cout << "4 ---> D " << endl;
        cout << "5 ---> Calculate" << endl;
        cout << "x ---> Exit" << endl;

        op = std::getchar();

        switch(op){
        case '1':
            cout<<"1";
            break;
        case '2':
            cout<<"2";
            break;
        case '3':
            cout<<"3";
            break;
        case '4':
            cout<<"4";
            break;
        case '5':
            cout<<"5";
            break;
        case 'x':
            return 0;
        default:
            continue;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, in the console I have seen the cout statements two times instead of one. A sample console looks like this:

```
Please select: 
1 ---> A
2 ---> B
3 ---> C 
4 ---> D 
5 ---> Calculate
x ---> Exit
1
1Please select: 
1 ---> A
2 ---> B
3 ---> C 
4 ---> D 
5 ---> Calculate
x ---> Exit
Please select: 
1 ---> A
2 ---> B
3 ---> C 
4 ---> D 
5 ---> Calculate
x ---> Exit
```

Any ideas on how to display cout statements only once after user makes selection?

Comment: You also need to initialize `op`, probably to something other than `'x'`

Comment: You are entering lines but reading characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you still have some characters in the input stream after

```
    op = std::getchar();
```

Add a line to ignore the rest of the line from the input stream.

```
    op = std::getchar();
    int temp;
    while ( (temp = std::getchar()) != '\n' && temp != EOF );
```

Comment: Yes, I believe the _extra stuff_ is associated with the usage of the 'Enter' key.

Comment: @RSahu I have added another related question. You can check it if you are interested in from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789578/getting-input-from-user-with-switch-c

Answer (score -1):

Just looking at your code, you probably should put an "endline" after you read a `char`

```
op=std::getchar();
std::cout<<endl;
```

also you probably don't need to output the user's response unless you're going to say something like "you entered 1". Since your options are listed before the user enters their selection you will see the options then they well enter their choice then the while loop will display the options yet again.